# transitioning from one view controller to another using a button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So, I created a login page with basic logic. If username and/or password are empty, it displays an error message. If they're full, then it transitions to the next page (home). I created a second ViewController on the storyboard, and created a SecondViewController". I then defined the respective ViewController class to "SecondViewController".

On the first ViewController.swift file, i used this code:

```
func transition(Sender:UIButton!)
{
    let secondViewController: SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

}
```

When I tested it out however, pressing the login button (when both the username and password are filled) transfers me to a black screen instead of the second View Controller. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the view to contain things added to it on the storyboard, you could give it a Storyboard ID (a couple of boxes below where you set the class of the view controller in the storyboard).

If you give it for example the ID "secondVC" you can then create it using the following:

```
let secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondVC") as? SecondViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize a view controller with just the default init method.

You should probably create a view controller scene in your storyboard, add a unique identifier on it, instantiate it using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, and then display it like you are doing.

Comment: You can _totally_ initialize a view controller with the default init method, you just can't expect that the view will be populated from the storyboard.

Comment: Or populated at all. It's view object will be blank. Thus the only type of view controller where this is helpful is one that overrides loadView to create it's view hierarchy manually.

Comment: The same issue exists when loading a view controller from an XIB. There you should use `initWithNibName:bundle:`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make a segue between the view controllers in your Storyboard, and call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier()`.

Or you can give your `UIViewController an identifier and present it programmatically too:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let secondViewController storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("") as? SecondViewController
if let secondViewController = secondViewController {
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three ways to do this

1)Creating segue in storyboard,though it will only work if you have single segue from that item

2)using prepareforSegue and performSegue Methods in your presenting view controller
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:    AnyObject?) {

```
if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
  let controller = segue.destinationViewController as!secondViewController
}
```

}

Then use this in your IBACtion

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("YourIdentifier", sender:sender)
```

3)(Recommended One)

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContactsVC")! as! ContactsVC 

self.presentViewController(controller, animated:true, completion:nil
```

---